# How BFS find the minimum path in maze solver

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, breadth-first-search

I'm stuck at the solution of a problem.

Problem =>
You are given a square grid with some cells open (.) and some blocked (X). Your playing piece can move along any row or column until it reaches the edge of the grid or a blocked cell. Given a grid, a start and a goal, determine the minimum number of moves to get to the goal.

```
Example =>
...
.X.
...
```

The starting position (0,0)  so start in the top left corner. The goal is (1,2) The path is (0,0)->(0,2)->(1,2). It takes  moves to reach the goal.
Output = 2

Solution=>
BFS using Queue.

But how BFS can get to the minimum path for example if there is more than one path exist between starting and ending point then how BFS can get to the minimum one ?

Here is my solution for the above problem. But it doesn't work.

```
class Pair{
int x,y;
Pair(int a,int b){x=a;y=b;}
}

class Result {  
public static int minimumMoves(List<String> grid, int startX, int startY, int goalX, int goalY) 
{
    int n=grid.get(0).length();

    ArrayDeque<Pair> q=new ArrayDeque<Pair>();
    Pair location[][]=new Pair[n][n];
    char color[][]=new char[n][n];
    
    //default color a mean it is neither in queue nor explore 
    //till now, b mean it is in queue, c means it already explore
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            color[i][j]='a';
        }
    }
    
    q.addLast(new Pair(startX,startY));
    
    int tempx,tempy,tempi,tempj;
    
    
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
            tempx=q.peekFirst().x;
            tempy=q.peekFirst().y;
            q.removeFirst();
            color[tempx][tempy]='c';
            tempj=tempy-1;
            tempi=tempx;

            //cheking unvisited node around -X axis
            while(tempj>=0){
                if(color[tempi][tempj]!='a' || grid.get(tempi).charAt(tempj)!='.'){
                    break;
                }
                q.addLast(new Pair(tempi,tempj));
                color[tempi][tempj]='b';
                location[tempi][tempj]=new Pair(tempx,tempy);
                tempj--;
            }
            
            //checking unvisited node around +X axis
            tempi=tempx;
            tempj=tempy+1;
            while(tempj<n){
                if(color[tempi][tempj]!='a' || grid.get(tempi).charAt(tempj)!='.'){
                    break;
                }
                q.addLast(new Pair(tempi,tempj));
                color[tempi][tempj]='b';
                location[tempi][tempj]=new Pair(tempx,tempy);
                tempj++;
            }
            
            //checking unvisited node around +Y axis
            tempi=tempx-1;
            tempj=tempy;
            while(tempi>=0){
                if(color[tempi][tempj]!='a' || grid.get(tempi).charAt(tempj)!='.'){
                    break;
                }
                q.addLast(new Pair(tempi,tempj));
                color[tempi][tempj]='b';
                location[tempi][tempj]=new Pair(tempx,tempy);
                tempi--;
            }
            
            checking unvisited node around -Y axis
            tempi=tempx+1;
            tempj=tempy;
            while(tempi<n){
                if(color[tempi][tempj]!='a' || grid.get(tempi).charAt(tempj)!='.'){
                    break;
                }
                q.addLast(new Pair(tempi,tempj));
                color[tempi][tempj]='b';
                location[tempi][tempj]=new Pair(tempx,tempy);
                tempi++;
            }
    }//end of main while

    //for track the path
    Stack<Pair> stack=new Stack<Pair>();
    
    //If path doesn't exist
    if(location[goalX][goalY]==null){
        return -1;
    }

    boolean move=true;
    stack.push(new Pair(goalX,goalY));
    while(move){
        tempi=stack.peek().x;
        tempj=stack.peek().y;
        stack.push(location[tempi][tempj]);
        if(tempi==startX && tempj==startY){
            move=false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(stack);
    return stack.size()-2;
}

}
```

Here My algorithm only find the path. Not the minimum path. Can anyone suggest me how BFS finds the minimum path here and what should I change into my code ?

Comment: This isn't BFS - you wrote `addFirst` to put a new node into the deque, and `peekFirst` to get the next one, so you are using the deque as a stack, not a queue. So this is DFS, not BFS.

Comment: @kaya3 Hi I updated my question. Please take a look now.

Comment: @Surt please read the question carefully. Actually (0,2), (0,3), (0,4).. is also adjacent to (0,0) if and only if these cells contains ".", if not then further nodes is not adjacent.

Comment: @Surt For better understanding please visit https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/castle-on-the-grid/problem

Comment: "Actually (0,2), (0,3), (0,4).. is also adjacent to (0,0) if and only if these cells contains ".", if not then further nodes is not adjacent." - no, I don't think that how grids or "adjacent" work.

Comment: Also, this isn't a maze. It's an open terrain with maybe a few obstacles (no walls) A BFS should work fine for a maze, but this here isn't one.

Comment: "Adjacent" means that you can get from one cell to the other in **one** step.

Comment: @Rajatkashyap: actually, you're right about this one. My apologies. According to the problem description, a piece _can_ move several cells in one step. So in that sense they are "adjacent". A problem in your algorithm might be in color management. Once you mark a cell "b" or "c", it won't ever be picked up again as a candidate for a cell in a shortest path.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So can you suggest me what should I changed in my code ?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. adjacent mean here is that (0,0) is adjacent to (0,1), (0,2), (0,3) and so on if and only if in these cell no one contain obstacle. If (0,3) contains obstacle then (0,3),(0,4) etc these are not adjacent to (0,1).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. and a piece can move several cells in one step.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. please take a look here https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/castle-on-the-grid/problem

Comment: Yes, if you are trying to find the shortest distance in terms of rook moves, then this is the right definition of adjacent.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.Now when you understand the question can you please tell me how BFS finds the minimum moves here ?

Comment: Yours doesn't. You need to keep track of the length of the path that leads to each point, and update it if you find a shorter path. So you need a 2D array of lengths. You may want to read about Dijkstra's algorithm which is a straightforward adaptation of BFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BFS finds the minimal path by concentric moving outward, so everything in round 1 is 1 away from start, all squares added there are then 2 away from start and so on. This means the basic idea of using BFS to find the path is good, unfortunately the implementation is a bit difficult and slow.

Another way of viewing it is to think about the grid as a graph, with all squares connected to all other squares up, down, left and right until they hit the edge or an obstacle.

A third way of thinking of it is like a flood fill, first round only start is filled, next round all that can be accessed from it is filled and so on.

---

The major thing is that you break when you see a `b`.

```
aabbaaaaaa
aabbbaaaaa
babbbaaaaa
babbbaaaaa
babbbaaaaa
babbbaaaaa
bbbbbaaaaa
bbbbbaaaaa
bCbbbAAAAA
cccccaaaaa
```

When processing the capital `C`it stops because it is surrounded by `b`s and `c`s. And therefore you don't examine the `A`s.

I have hacked the code a bit, note i'm not a java programmer ... my main problem when trying to solve it was timeouts. I believe this can be solved without the location array by recording how many generations of BFS we run, that should save a lot of memory and time.

```
class Pair{
    int x,y;
    Pair(int a,int b){x=a;y=b;}
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + x + "," + y + "]";
    }
}

class Result {

    /*
     * Complete the 'minimumMoves' function below.
     *
     * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
     * The function accepts following parameters:
     *  1. STRING_ARRAY grid
     *  2. INTEGER startX
     *  3. INTEGER startY
     *  4. INTEGER goalX
     *  5. INTEGER goalY
     */
 
    public static int minimumMoves(List<String> grid, int startX, int startY, int goalX, int goalY) {
    
    if (startX==goalX&&startY==goalY)
        return 0;
        
    startX += 1;
    startY += 1;
    goalX += 1;
    goalY += 1;
        
    int n=grid.get(0).length();

    Pair dirs[] = {new Pair(-1,0), new Pair(+1,0), new Pair(0,-1), new Pair(0,+1)};

    ArrayDeque<Pair> q=new ArrayDeque<Pair>();
    Pair location[][]=new Pair[n+2][n+2];
    char color[][]=new char[n+2][n+2];
    
    //default color a mean it is neither in queue nor explore 
    //till now, b mean it is in queue, c means it already explore
    for(int i=0;i<n+2;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n+2;j++){
            if (i == 0 || i == n+1 ||j == 0 || j == n+1 || // boarder
                grid.get(i-1).charAt(j-1)!='.')
                color[i][j]='x';
            else
                color[i][j]='a';
        }
    }
    
    q.addLast(new Pair(startX,startY));
    
    int tempx,tempy,tempi,tempj;
    
    
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        tempx=q.peekFirst().x;
        tempy=q.peekFirst().y;
        q.removeFirst();
        if(location[goalX][goalY]!=null){
            System.out.println("Goal reached");
            break;
        }
        color[tempx][tempy]='c';
        
        for (Pair dir : dirs ) {
            tempi=tempx;
            tempj=tempy;

            while(true){
                tempi+=dir.x;
                tempj+=dir.y;

                if (color[tempi][tempj]=='x') { // includes boarder
                    break;
                }
                if (color[tempi][tempj]>='b') {
                    continue;
                }
                q.addLast(new Pair(tempi,tempj));
                color[tempi][tempj]='b';
                location[tempi][tempj]=new Pair(tempx,tempy);                
            }
        }            

        // System.out.println(location[goalX][goalY]);
        // for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
        //     for(int j = 1; j < n+1; j++) {
        //         System.out.printf("%c", color[i][j]);
        //     }
        //     System.out.println();
        // }

    }//end of main while

    //for track the path
    Stack<Pair> stack=new Stack<Pair>();
    
    //If path doesn't exist
    if(location[goalX][goalY]==null){
        System.out.printf("Gaol not reached %d %d", goalX, goalY);
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j < n+1; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%s", location[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        return -1;
    }

    boolean move=true;
    int moves = 0;
    tempi = goalX;
    tempj = goalY;
    while(move){
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(tempi)+" "+ String.valueOf(tempj));
        moves = moves +1;
        Pair cur = location[tempi][tempj];
        tempi=cur.x;
        tempj=cur.y;
        if(tempi==startX && tempj==startY){
            move=false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(moves);
    return moves;
   }

}
```

Comment: that also doesn't work. I tried that too.

Comment: @Rajatkashyap updated, as you might see it runs by using BFS and is essentially the same code you made, the major change is that I look beyond the 'b's.